# if en linea php no funciona

Tags: php, html

Tengo este código

```
<?php
$country=$result['pais'];
} 
$strSQL = "SELECT id, nombre FROM paises";
$query = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
$totalrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
?>
<select class="form-control" name="acccountry">
    <?php
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
        <option <?php ($r == $country) ? 'selected' : '' ;?> value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"><?php echo $result['nombre'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Antes de eso tengo una consulta de otra tabla en la que me sale el código de un pais, por eso tengo la variable `$country`. Lo que quiero es que vaya recorriendo la tabla y donde coincidan las ID me ponga esa opción como `selected` en los `<option>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta `echo`:

```
<?php echo ($r == $country) ? 'selected' : '' ;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa:

```
<?php echo ($r == $country) ? 'selected' : '' ;?>
```

O la versión abreviada:

```
<?= ($r == $country) ? 'selected' : '' ?>
```